# Stop Scrolling of page when user comes to end of scrollable fixed element

Tags: html, css

The sidebar and main content is staying next to each other in the page.

1. sidebar is fixed with scroll auto
2. main-content is normal

see this pen http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/QdXmQm

```css
.sidebar{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  overflow:auto;
}

.main{
  background:silver;
  color:black;
  width:80%;
  float:right;
}

.main p{
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="main">
    <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p> <p>Main Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p> <p>sidebar content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Actual Result:**
Here when the user scrolls the sidebar and comes to the end of the sidebar, main content content is scrolled when the user scrolls more, entire page is scrolled.

**Expected Result:**
Here when the user scrolls the sidebar and comes to the end of the sidebar, main content content should not be scrolled.

Is there any way to achieve this?. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.sidebar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: silver;
  color: black;
}

.main p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="main">

    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>
    <p>Main Content</p>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>
    <p>sidebar content</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**You need to separate both the divs in order to have their own scrolls.**

This CSS should do the trick.

```
.main{

      position:fixed;
      width:80%;
      height:100%;
      left:20%;
      overflow:auto;
      background:silver;
      color:black;

    }
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/KajoJG

Comment: Without separation, you will have end up with your initial stage.